# ¿Convertir consulta SQL a estructura eloquent de Laravel?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent, querybuilder

Tengo una tabla (MySql) que cuenta con una columna de codigo y una columna que contiene un JSON, el cual consta de un arreglo de objetos

[image: Tabla de movimientos]

mediante la siguiente consulta logro separar el JSON en diferentes registros

```
SELECT tt.code, m.movement, m.date, m.time FROM temp_table tt, JSON_TABLE(
tt.moves, 
'$[*]' COLUMNS (
  movement VARCHAR(80) PATH '$.movement', 
  date date PATH '$.date',
  time time PATH '$.time'
)) as m
```

lo cual me muestra el siguiente resultado

[image: resultado de consulta]

Pero requiero usar esta consulta en Laravel, replicandola ya sea usando Eloquent, o bien, Query Builder pero no he logrado hacerlo

Agradecería mucho si alguien me puede orientar con este problema

Answer (score 0):

Laravel es agnóstico en cuanto al motor de base de datos, por lo que el query builder no te servirá para ejecutar features propietarias.`JSON_TABLE` no funcionará más que en MySQL 8.0, rompiendo la capa de abstracción que debe mantener compatibilidad con MySQL 5.7 y MariaDB. Si bien otras plataformas tienen maneras de convertir JSON en una colección de registros (como  [json_each](https://database.guide/sqlite-json_each/) de SQLite e indirectamente UNNEST en PostgreSQL) se apunta al 80/20).

Si te sirve de consuelo, la versión dev de PostgreSQL, que es la 15, incorpora [JSON_TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONTABLE), así que puede que en un futuro cercano se haga estándar de facto. Por mientras, sólo te quera ejecutar una consulta contra el conector PDO nativo.

Por ejemplo, con SQLite ([json_each](https://database.guide/sqlite-json_each/)) sería algo como:

```
      $result=DB::connection()
               ->getPdo()
               ->query(
               'SELECT code, moves,  key, value FROM tt, json_each(moves)'
                )->fetchAll();
```

Donde key y value son las columnas imaginarias por defecto de la tabla JSON generada al vuelo.

**Respecto a Eloquent**... no tiene sentido la pregunta. Eloquent es un ORM, No trae "filas" sino instancias de un modelo. A la hora de representarlos, claro, esos modelos se castean transparentemente a arreglos en la medida que hayan sido bien definidos.

Tomándome de tu ejemplo, ya que pusiste el código como imagen y no voy a transcribir, voy a usar una tabla imaginaria `rentals`:

```
   Schema::create('rentals', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id('code');
        $table->json('moves'); 
    });
```

Cuyo contenido será

| code | moves |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | '[{ "year": "2002", "type": "Chevrolet" }, { "year": "2006", "type": "Peugeot" }]' |
| 2 | '[{ "year": "2007", "type": "Toyota" }, { "year": "2003", "type": "Fiat" }]' |

Declararé su modelo indicando que el atributo `moves` debe castearse como colección (aunque, para el caso, también podría usar `array` u `object`)

```
class Rental extends Model {

    protected $primaryKey = 'code';

    public $timestamps = false; 

    protected $casts = ['moves' => 'collection'];
}
```

Con esto, la consulta más simple entregará un array en donde `moves` a su vez es un array anidado:

```
 dd( Rental::select(['code','moves'])->get());

[
    {
        "code": 1,
        "moves": [
            {
                "year": "2002",
                "type": "Chevrolet"
            },
            {
                "year": "2006",
                "type": "Peugeot"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "code": 2,
        "moves": [
            {
                "year": "2007",
                "type": "Toyota"
            },
            {
                "year": "2003",
                "type": "Fiat"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

La naturaleza del casteo de un campo JSON, en Eloquent, es anidar los arreglos (como lo haría, por ejemplo, MongoDB), versus la manera tabular de tu pregunta, que es la única que MySQL conoce para enumerar registros.

Manipulando un poco esos datos se puede mostrar tablas anidadas. No es lo mismo pero ya te dejé más que encaminado:

```css
table {
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 0.2em 1em !important;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.9.4/css/bulma.min.css" integrity="sha512-HqxHUkJM0SYcbvxUw5P60SzdOTy/QVwA1JJrvaXJv4q7lmbDZCmZaqz01UPOaQveoxfYRv1tHozWGPMcuTBuvQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<table class="table is-bordered is-fullwidth">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Code</th>
      <th>Moves</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>
        <table class="table is-bordered is-hoverable is-fullwidth is-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>year</th>
              <th>type</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>2002</td>
              <td>Chevrolet</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>2006</td>
              <td>Peugeot</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>

        <table class="table is-bordered is-fullwidth is-striped is-hoverable">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>year</th>
              <th>type</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>2007</td>
              <td>Toyota</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>2003</td>
              <td>Fiat</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[Puedes ver esto funcionando en este snippet de Laravel Playground.](https://laravelplayground.com/#/snippets/b15b2e76-e1c6-4f3c-9cd5-103e5b75d9e1)